# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, guiminer

I am giving this a try to see if I can do bitcoin mining. I took a Windows laptop and installed GUIMiner on it. I then connected to bitminter pool on http://mint.bitminter.com:8332 using my ID. When I click to start Mining, I get this message "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack". The summary then says "connection problems".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: I got exact same issue with GUIMiner. Only I tried to use it with btcguild instead of bitminer. Installing AMD-APP-SDK-v2.8-Windows-32.exe and rebooting PC helped (AMD-APP-SDK-v2.8-Windows-32.exe is for ATI graphic cards - there's some counterpart for nVidia, but I don't know it). My guess is that issue comes from missing DLLs.

Comment: I think I'm going to give up on Bitcoin mining. I probably don't even have the hardware powerful enough to make a dent. From what I hear, the only way to make money is by purchasing a ButterflyLabs Bitcoin Miner device. And an alternative to mining is buy/sell trading with dollar cost averaging.

Comment: Could be a problem with username or password

Comment: I've reopened this question, because at 10,000 views, it doesn't appear to be too localized. related: [GUIMiner gives "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/19269/5406)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting this error. Like the above answer states, I checked my password, saw that it was longer than it should have been and changed it, then quit getting the error. At least for me, it was a wrong username/password.