# GUIMiner gives "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Tags: miner-configuration, guiminer

[image: heres a screen shot]

I'm trying to get started mining with kiv's `GUIMiner`. I started, and get this error message:

> `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

How should I solve this?

Comment: Bitcoin mining with CPU or GPU is not profitable anymore. You'll get more bitcoins from a faucet. My 2¢.